# Copying a word from a file to a struct object and I am getting seg faults

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
//fin here is a file that contains one word per line, with many lines
void* buildTypeWord(FILE* fin){
    char temp[100];
    Word* aWord =(Word*)calloc(1,sizeof(Word));
    fgets(temp,100,fin);
    strip(temp); //strips off the new line characters and replaces with a \0
    aWord->ltrs=(char*)calloc(strlen(temp)+1,sizeof(char));
    strcpy(aWord->ltrs, temp);
    aWord->len=strlen(temp);
    printf("%s",aWord->ltrs); //just me bug testing
    free(temp);
    printf("%s",aWord->ltrs); //just me bug testing
    return aWord;
}
```

This method is supposed to take a word from the file that is passed in and attach that word to a word object. For what ever reason something here is causing the program to seg fault.

On a side note unless I have that free(temp) there no information about the seg fault is given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not call `free(temp)`, as you have not allocated the memory block pointed by `temp` dynamically.

Comment: i figured as much, but i still dont know whats cause the seg dump

Comment: @ChrisBettis: Have you just changed your question based on this answer???

Comment: @ChrisBettis Please do not edit your question as it will be very confusing for later readers.

Answer (score 0):

The (input) argument to `free` must be one that's returned by one of `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.  Anything else leads to undefined behavior.  In your case, you are **lucky** that your passing an array on the stack lead to a seg-fault.

Comment: To be precise, the C-language standard does not dictate that local variables are allocated on the stack (in fact, it does not even define what a stack is). Although by far the most common method, it is nevertheless compiler-implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `free` the array `temp[]`, since it is an automatic variable and will be cleaned up when you return from the `buildTypeWord()` function. On the other hand, you should be keeping track of the memory that you are allocating for `Word`s as well as the memory pointed to by the various `ltrs` fields within the `Word`s, so that you can free it at an appropriate time.